# Windows 10 non quick format

Tags: windows-10, formatting

What exactly and precisely Win10 non quick format does that quick format doesn't? I ask because I keep finding different answers. Some say it writes zeros to the drive, some say it only scans for bad sectors in addition (hence it takes so long). If it conducts a scan, why there's no log to be found anywhere?

Comment: "some say it only scans for bad sectors in addition (hence it takes so long). "   <-- check your hard drive for errors. Quick Format (now just regular format) is normally very quick.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior changed starting with Windows Vista. Quick format has not changed, it does not write 0's

> The behavior of the format command changed in Windows Vista and later Windows versions. By default in Windows Vista and later versions, the format command writes zeros to the whole disk when a full format is performed. In Windows XP and earlier versions of Windows, the format command does not write zeros to the whole disk when a full format is performed.

[Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/941961/change-in-the-behavior-of-the-format-command-in-windows-vista-and-late)

Answer (score 1):

**Quick format** will only lay down a blank
[File Allocation Table (FAT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table)
and directory table and that's all. It checks nothing and will only detect errors
that happen while writing the above relatively small amount of data
(in which case the disk is bad).
It will finish by marking the disk or partition as "formatted".

**Full format** from Vista and later will write zeroes to the disk in the data part of the
disk sectors, but will also renew the address part of the sector (where the sector
identifies itself to avoid addressing errors). This will detect errors that normally
the disk firmware will relocate into the spare sectors, or will
otherwise mark these sectors as bad and unusable.

Full format will finally also write a blank FAT and directory table
in addition to the volume label.

Quick format should only be used for disks that one is sure are in good form
(checking the [SMART data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.)
of the disk is one way to be sure).
If the disk is known or suspected as having errors, Full format can "fix" it
by finding and marking these spots.
Sometimes the problem with the disk is fading magnetism, which the act of rewriting
sector headers and zeroing the data will renew as good as new.

Full format is much slower and may take an appreciable
time for a modern multi-terabytes disk.
Quick Format is extremely quick.